# How can i setup a spinnaker stage to compare 2 prometheus metrics and decide whether or not to continue the pipeline

Tags: bash, deployment, spinnaker

Lets say my app pushes 2 metrics to prometheus
Metric A, Metric B

I have a requirement where i would like to compare the above
`sum(rate(MetricA{})) > sum(rate(MetricA{}))`

The stage should fail depending ho how this expression gets evaluated

I came across the `Script` and `Webhook` stages while looking around to achieve this, but could not get enough details on their usage

Looking for help as to how this can be achieved using any of the above 2 steps. Please suggest if there is something beyond these 2 as well. Will explore

I tried setting up the bash `Script` and `Webhook` stages, however couldnt find enough examples online